# nokogiri replace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I'm parsing an HTML document and trying to replace the image src.  It seems to do what I want when I attempt it in the console however in my model it doesn't seem to save it.  Now, I'm not sure if what I'm doing is wrong with the way to save in Rails (i'm trying to update the content field and replacing external images with local ones) or if it's using nokogiri, but it's not saving the result using the `set_attribute` method

It does the rest of it perfectly.

```
  before_save :replace_zemanta_images

  def replace_zemanta_images
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(content)
    unless doc.css('div.zemanta-img').blank?
      doc.css('div.zemanta-img img').each do |img|
        io = open(URI.parse(img[:src]))
        if photos.find_by_data_remote_url(img[:src]).blank?
          photo = photos.build(:data => io, :data_remote_url => img[:src])
          img.set_attribute('src', photo.data.url(:original)) #doesn't work!
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that `content` is an attribute on your model.

When you are doing `img.set_attribute` you are updating the attribute in the `Nokogiri::XML::Element` object but this doesn't update the text of `content`.

At the end of your method you will need to add something like:

```
self.content = doc.to_s
```

Comment: Perfect, I knew I was overlooking something!  Thanks

Comment: I also noticed that Nokogiri seems to be throwing in a <HTML doctype> and body tag... regardless if it was there or not.  Any idea how to prevent it from doing that?

Comment: There are often slight differences between the HTML that you feed into Nokogiri and the HTML you get out by doing `doc.to_s`. This is a consequence of it going through the parser and as far as I know there is no way to avoid it.

Comment: You probably want to use 
`doc = Nokogiri::HTTP::DocumentFragment.parse(content)`
DocumentFragment doesn't wrap it with <html> or <body> tags, it takes it as is.

Answer (score 0):

JackChance mentioned to use `Nokogiri::HTTP::DocumentFragment.parse(content)` here for a fragment (if you don't want DOCTYPE/HTML/BODY tags), I didn't have any luck with that since my original HTML was a snippet instead of the whole document.

I ended up using something like this:
`html = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment`
to initially convert the HTML string snippet to a Nokogiri object without the unnecessary tags.

Then once we use `img.set_attribute`, we can convert back `html.to_s`